# Forkmik handleChange not updating dropdown value in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to use **Form.Select from semantic ui react** to build a dropdrown. I'm sending an array of objects with the following properties to fill dropdown options:

```
DelivererForDropdown = {
                          key: deliverer.id,
                          value: deliverer.id,
                          text: deliverer.userName,
                          id: deliverer.id
                        };
```

The problem I'm facing is that the handleChange event from Formik is not updating my selection. I'm using this event for other inputs and it works well.

```
    <Form.Select 
      type="text"
      placeholder="Repartidor" 
      name="deliverer"
      options={deliverersForDropdown}
      search
      onChange={handleChange}
      error={errors.deliverer}
      value={values.deliverer}
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Formik function `setFieldValue()` to manually set the value in the handler `onChange()`:

```
 <Formik
      enableReinitialize={true}
      initialValues={initialValues}
      onSubmit={async (values, { resetForm }) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      }}
    >
      {({ isSubmitting, values, setFieldValue, setTouched, errors }) => {
        return (
          <FormikForm>
            <Form.Select
              type="text"
              placeholder="Repartidor"
              name="deliverer"
              options={deliverersForDropdown}
              search={true}
              onChange={(event, { value }) => {
                setFieldValue("deliverer", value);
                setTouched("deliverer", true);
              }}
              error={errors.deliverer}
              value={values.deliverer}
            />
            <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
              SUBMIT
            </button>
          </FormikForm>
        );
      }}
 </Formik>
```

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-forked-x4ior?file=/index.js:490-1416)

Alternatively you can use a 3rd party that automatically binds, for example [formik-semantic-ui](https://github.com/turner-industries/formik-semantic-ui)